# SearchDisplayController hide searchResultsTableView and show underlaying table view disables scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, scroll, searchdisplaycontroller

I have a tableview with a searchDisplayController and three different search scopes. For the two first scopes I want to display the search results in the standard searchResultsTableView. For the last one I want to hide the searchResultsTableView and show the tableview underneath with some custom appearance in the first table view cell. This works well.

My problem is that the scrolling of the underlaying tableview is not working. The scroll indicator is flashing and I'm able to select cells, which means that UserInteractionEnabled = YES. What can possibly disable the scrolling? The scrollview delegate method scrollViewDidEndDragging is called but not scrollViewDidScroll.

Anyone got any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Found this now but it doesn't solve my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702945/reloading-displaying-searchresultstableview-of-uisearchdisplaycontroller-after

Comment: Have you checked ```[tableView isScrollEnabled]```?

Comment: It tells me that scrolling is not enabled. I have tried `[tableView setScrollEnabled:YES]` and that changes the scrolling to enabled. However the tableview still won't scroll. I decided to not spend more time on this problem and changed the design slightly to avoid this.